# Metal roof ROI?

Tags: roof, metal-roof

Wondering if there is anyone out there who has completely replaced their asphalt roof with metal (*standing seam and/or metal shingles*). I want to know how well metal roofs hold up and how (or if) they're valued by home-owners and home-buyers.

Our asphalt shingles are nearing the end of their life and we are looking at options between replacing with 30-year asphalt and metal (concealed and/or unexposed fasteners). We are considering metal because of it's lifespan; most manufacturers have a 50-year warranty, while some people have said it can last in excess of 60 years depending on conditions. Also, there are some styles that go beyond the standing seam look and are quite nice.

We have already received quotes for both asphalt and metal, which vary greatly (metal shingles was the highest bid at 4 times greater than asphalt in North Carolina). Not sure I'm willing to spend over $25k to replace a roof, but I'm curious to other people's opinions about this and had a few questions.

1. How has the roof held up over time?
2. What type of roof and price per square footage?
3. Did you sell your house fairly soon  afterwards and if so how did that affect your home value?

Comment: there's a lot of different types of metal roofs

Comment: Wish I was in NC - in Australia you could be looking at around $40K AUD for a large metal roof and gutters (depending on the exchange rate $25-35KUSD) ..

Comment: Wonder what the price per size is? Mine was almost $13 USD ($29,000 at 2,250 sqft)

Comment: Unfortunately the pricing part of the question is off-topic. My gut feel is that the rest of it is opinion based, but I'm not going to VtC just yet. These are very valid questions, I just don't think they're a good fit for the SE format.

Comment: Yes, "metal roof" is quite vague. Please revise to be more specific, and remove all mention of cost.

Comment: Metal has a positive ROI in my area the metal shingles I would not touch as they are way more expensive and 10 years later try to get replacements after a storm (had a friend go through that). In most cases the do help a sale but I know 1 man that thought he did not like standing seam because it was slippery and he was afraid to get on the roof and clean the needles and moss, well until I asked him have you seen a metal roof with moss or needles? (A problem in some areas of the Pacific Northwest) he now has a standing seam metal roof , metal shingles have same problems as comp with needles.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for the info! Yeah I think the shingles are way out of my price range, it's just that I have a hard time picturing the home with standing seam.

Comment: Standing seam can look nice even on homes with valleys, there are many different colors available I tend to use neutral/ pastel colors. in my area green and brown are really is well received in a forested area. Red for a farm house but to me red makes me think of a barn.

Comment: Are you looking to have a fairly maintenance-free and worry-free roof for 50 years or are you looking to sell your home and re-coup the costs? For the latter you would have to talk with a knowledgeable realtor in your area and get an idea of what other people are doing. If you're in a "keeping up with the Jones's neighborhood" then follow the lead of the neighborhood. A metal roof has a premium price tag because it is factually better than asphalt. The biggest mistake you could make is choosing a bad color.

Comment: More focused on a maintenance free roof. I'm fairly well aware of the benefits of metal v. asphalt, aesthetically and structurally. But I'm wondering how those benefits translate into dollars, even when you diminishing returns on homes and home renovations.

Comment: @JamesR. -- think of how many asphalt shingle roofs you'd need to equal the working lifespan of a standing-seam metal roof, that'll get you in the ballpark